# .Rproj files disappear from project directories in R CMD CHECK environment

Tags: r, unit-testing, environment, package-development

I'm working on developing an R package that reads/checks user file structure. Some functions in the package check to see if an `.Rproj` file exists in a given directory.

I've written a test for one of those functions using `testthat`, but am running into an issue that keeps making my test fail.

I have a folder in `tests/testthat` that contains a project made up of an `.Rproj` file, a `.Rmd` and an `html` output file. When I try to access the folder interactively in the console using `fs::dir_ls`, all three files show up as expected, but when running `R CMD CHECK`, I only see  the `.Rmd` and the `html`. The `.Rproj` file appears to disappear into thin air.

This is the code I run:

==== INTERACTIVE (console) ====

`fs::dir_ls("tests/testthat/project_noob")`

Output:

`tests/testthat/project_noob/project_noob.Rproj`
`tests/testthat/project_noob/simple.Rmd`
`tests/testthat/project_noob/simple.html`

==== R CMD CHECK ====

`dir <- test_path("project_noob")`
`fs::dir_ls(dir)`

Output:

`project_noob/simple.Rmd`
`project_noob/simple.html`

Does anyone know why this might be? Is there something about the `R CMD CHECK` testing environment that hides `.Rproj` files? Is there a way to unhide them?

Comment: `readLines('project_noob/.Rbuildignore')`

Comment: @MichaelChirico Clearing .Rproj from the `.Rbuildignore` file for the package (not the project) seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: if you plan on submitting the package to CRAN, be sure to double check that `R CMD CHECK --as-cran` isn't complaining about unrecognized files in the project folder